# Does protein lower the glycemic load? Please explain

Tags: diabetes

Let's say you eat 50 grams of potato chips which have a glycemic load of 12 (according to Harvard.edu) and you eat it with 1 oz. Of sunflower seeds with have a GI load of 2.5. So is the total GI load then 14.5 ?

Does the protein have any affect or lower the glycemic load?

If yes please explain. **What is the calculation by which you can know how much the glycemic load is lowered?**

Comment: Glycemic loads are affected by many factors including personal differences, so I do not believe it is possible to calculate glycemic loads of mixed meals with accuracy of any practical meaning. Adding sunflower seeds (protein + fats) lowers the glycemic load of the potato chips, so the glycemic load of such mixed meal would be somewhere between 2.5 and 12.

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple yes.
Exact ratio I don't know if it's conclusive however here is a study with their opinion on the ratio http://m.jn.nutrition.org/content/136/10/2506.full

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the calculation by which you can know by how much the glycemic load is lowered?

Comment: Could you explain the link you have provided a little bit? If the link dies, then this answer wouldn't have anything to back it up.